# Twisting a bundle so that it has a section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(X, H)$ be a smooth, polarized, projective, irreducible variety. Let $F$ be a vector bundle (or generally a coherent sheaf with positive dimensional support) on it.

Can we always say that there exists an integer $t$ such that $H^0(X, F \otimes H^{\otimes t}) \neq 0$ but $H^0(X, F \otimes H^{\otimes k}) =0$ for all $k <t$?

Is there a way to show this by contradiction? and can this $t$ be precisely determined?

Comment: For vector bundles this can be proven using Serre duality and Serre's vanishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want $\dim X>0$. Also, let me assume $H$ is very ample. If $F$ is a vector bundle, such a $t$ exists. For arbitrary coherent sheaves, to have vanishing, you need minor hypothesis, like no zero dimensional associated primes. Explicitly finding such a  $t$ is usually not easy and will depend on what you know about $F$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could you please briefly indicate the argument for the existence of such a $t$ for a vector bundle $F$ on a variety?

Comment: As @danneks has said, it is an easy application of Serre duality and Serre vanishing.